# Multiple Dictums for a chapter

Tags: chapters, koma-script, quoting

I would like to have more than one quote at the start of a chapter. I am using the `dictum` environment with `scrreprt`. If I do two back to back dictums, it simply ignores the first and proceeds with the second. Any solutions?

Comment: Perhaps you should try with the `epigraph` [package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epigraph).

Comment: Being an experienced user of the site, it would have been nice if  you were adding a MWE. Can you please add one?

Answer (score 5):

This illustrates the default layout of the `epigraphs` environment which supports multiple quotations:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{epigraph,url}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{In The Beginning}
  \begin{epigraphs}
    \qitem{Friendship with oneself is all-important, because without it one cannot be friends with anyone else in the world.}{Eleanor Roosevelt}
    \qitem{No man remains quite what he was when he recognizes himself.}{Thomas Mann}
  \end{epigraphs}
  Some text.
  Quotations from \url{http://www.quotationspage.com/}. (I'm assuming two counts as a `small number' and that it is therefore acceptable to use them here.)
\end{document}
```

[image: multiple epigraphs for the first chapter]

Answer (score 5):

Please always provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

> I am using the `dictum` environment

KOMA-Script does not have a `dictum` *environment* but a `\dictum` command!

> If I do two back to back dictums, it simply ignores the first and
>   proceeds with the second.

I can't reproduce this when I use the command the way it is shown in the KOMA-Script manual.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\dictum[Wes Montgomery]{%
  I never practice my guitar -- from time to time I just open the case and
  throw in a piece of raw meat.%
}
\dictum[Jeff Beck]{%
  I don't care about the rules. If I don't break the rules at least ten
  times every song then I'm not doing my job.%
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]